# Unwanted Back Button

Tags: lwuit, lwuit-form, lwuit-button

hiii guysss

i m new to LWUIT 
i had created some forms in LWUIT using TABS...

when I go to any list, I got back button automatically `added at the bottom of tabs..`
Can anyone help me to remove this back button....???
This back button comes only after clicking any list that is containing in the first page but when I click any of list item it makes to move on to another page but in another page `automatically this back button added...`

**Remove Back Button Under TABS...**

[image]

thanx in advance....

Comment: post the code. Then only others can help.

Comment: its command i haven't code anything..
its just design & its got disappear in 3rd form...
1st Form = not show
2nd Form = show
3rd Form = not show

Comment: u have to remove back or add back to 3rd form?

Comment: using LWUIT Resource Editor...

Answer (score 1):

Trick in Lwuit Resource Editor

1. Select a button in the form
2. On Right side you can see the properties -> command -click on command a dialog will be open
3. Now Assign following Action  =  Back BackCommand = tick just give ok.

Run your project now !

your back button will not be visible.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think formObject.removeAllCommands(); when you initialize the form should also work.